# Number of page views per page

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone tell me how to display (individual) page views from users. I have 5 web pages in my website and when I place the following php code in all pages it shows the same no of page views instead of no of views per page.

Note; I'm still a newbie in web designin.

Here is my code,
**counter.php**

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());  mysql_select_db("myinfo_db") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1");


 $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM counter"));


 echo "$count[0]";

?>
```

Comment: arr a page colum, then `update .. where page =PAGE` or install goolge analytic and let that do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify for which page you're increasing the page count. Your table should look something like: id - primary key & counter - the current page count

Each page will be assigned a unique id and all operations will done against that id. For example:

```
$currentPageId = 1; // let's say this is index.php, for other pages you have 2, 3 and so on
// update page count for the current page
mysql_query("UPDATE `counter` SET `counter` = `counter` + 1 WHERE `id` = $currentPageId");

// fetch the page count for the current page
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT `counter` FROM `counter` WHERE `id` = $currentPageId"));
```

Good luck!

Comment: You must put $currentPageId outside of string and concat it with string.

Answer (score 2):

Your `counter` table should have at least 3 columns: id, page, and views.

So when a user visits, lets say homepage, then update views for that page using

```
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET views = views + 1 WHERE page = 'homepage'");
```

then when displaying views for homepage only, you use:

```
mysql_query("SELECT views FROM counter WHERE page = 'homepage'");
```

I hope that helps.